# Axios calls api, but does not return data to client

Tags: express, vue.js

I am trying to restrict a page viewing an instance of Upload in a VueJS app to members of a specific Group.

However, I can't seem to retrieve the group. axios hits the api, and I can see in terminal that the rout returns data, but for some reason, no data gets to the client side.

HEre is my Vue componenet method:

```
async getGroupById() {
  console.log('getting group by id: ', this.upload.groups_id)
  let result = await GroupsService.getGroupById({
    id: this.upload.groups_id
  })
  this.uploadGroup = result 
  console.log('group by id result is: ', this.uploadGroup)
  // this.uploadGroup = result.data
  // console.log('group is gotten')
}
```

here is my service action:

```
async getGroupById (params) {
    console.log('in service getting group with id: ', params.id)
    let response = await axios.get('groups/' + params.id)
    console.log ('this is the response: ', response.data)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.data;
    }
  }
```

and here is my express route.

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('in groups id is: ', id)
  let results = await Group.query().findById( id ).eager('user');
  console.log('this is the group found: ', results)
  res.json(results);
});
```

console logs all fire up through the express route, but after that eg this one:

```
 console.log ('this is the response: ', response.data)
```

doesn't get called.

Comment: Did you see 'console.log('getting group by id:' in browser console? Did you see console.log('group by id result is: ' ?

Comment: I see `getting group by id:  1`. I do not see the console log of the result.

Comment: and in the Network tab of dev tools do you see completed request with status 200?

Comment: yes 200, with the response object there and in the server logs which is correct.

Comment: Everything is good through the request and the express response, I just get nothing back on the Vue side

Comment: output the whole 'result' object to console and look at it

Comment: I can't get anything to the log in the chrome console after the request. even though  now see the request and the response in the network tab.

Comment: That there's 200 in network tab but no response in the app usually means that there's CORS problem. But in this case there should be console error.

Comment: It is very strange that I see 200 response, I see the response data in the network tab, and I can't get it in the component or in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a try catch around the axios call `let response = await axios.get('groups/' + params.id)` line to see whats wrong.

```
try {
     let response = await axios.get('groups/' + params.id);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error response:");
      console.error(err.response.data); // ***
      console.error(err.response.status); // ***
      console.error(err.response.headers); // ***
    }
```